# Create SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, select

I have a table registration with a single field EmailId.
The user are enter email id like sourab@winworldsoft.com at the time of registration. i want to get the value between @ and .(dot) and store into the database table company.

i has try some basic query wildcard query.
Like operator

SQl Query for table.

```
Create table registration(email varchar(20));
insert into registration values("sourabh@winworldsoft.com");
```

Can anybody help me? I would appreciate very much.

Thanks

Comment: you want the code in php or sql? @Saurabh Kumar

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
$emailadd="billy@somedomain.com";
$email_company = substr(strrchr($emailadd, "@"), 1);
echo $email_company;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using php,

you can get the value between @ and dot,

```
$email = "sourab@winworldsoft.com"
$value1 = explode('@',$email);
$value2 = explode('.',$value1[1]);

echo $value2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **AFTER INSERT TRIGGER** ON **registration** table to automatic insert into Company Table as below:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `AIR_registration`$$

CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'%' */
    TRIGGER `AIR_registration` AFTER INSERT ON `registration` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
END;
    INSERT INTO Company (companyName) 
    VALUES (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(NEW.email, '@', -1), '.', 1));
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to get the "company" would be using regexp.

```
<?php
  $re = '/.+@([^.]+).+/';
  $email = 'sourab@winworldsoft.com';

  preg_match($re, $email, $matches);

  echo $matches[1];
?>
```

In case the domain portion of the email has more than one dot and you want all except the last portion, you can also use:

```
<?php
  $re = '/.+@(.+)\..+/';
  $email = 'sourab@email.winworldsoft.com';

  preg_match($re, $email, $matches);

  echo $matches[1];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you will get result between @ and dot(.) like this

```
<?php
$email = "test@test.com";
$value1 = explode('@',$email);
$value2 = explode('.',$value1[1]);
echo $value2[0];
?>
```

OR in dynamic way using RE you will get result like this :

```
<?php
$re = '/.+@([^.]+).+/';
  $email = 'test@test.com';
  preg_match($re, $email, $match);
  echo $match[1];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try...

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('sourabh@winworldsoft.com', (CHARINDEX('@', 'sourabh@winworldsoft.com')+1), (len('sourabh@winworldsoft.com')+1-(CHARINDEX('.',reverse('sourabh@winworldsoft.com'))))-(CHARINDEX('@', 'sourabh@winworldsoft.com')+1));
```